# Wordpress - Autoplay home page video with Gateway theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Wordpress Gateway theme. Part of the theme is a video area. This is setup under Customize -> Theme Options -> Homepage Template. It allows you to specify the URL for a video and them some HTML for content to appear beside it. I want the video to autoplay when it becomes visible

My video is hosted by vimeo.com. I cannot find a way to autoplay. The obvious things like putting ?autoplay=1 on the end of the URL do not work.

Any ideas who to make it autoplay?

I can use something other than vimeo if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the end of the line:

```
&amp;autoplay=1
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q49fp6gb/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly that doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me. Please check my answer above, I posted jsfiddle link.

Comment: Well sure if you write your own HTML it works, but can you persuade the Wordpress Gateway theme to autoplay?